# Analysis on Alekhine-Lasker 1934, after 18.Qd6

Tags: analysis

In this position [from Alekhine-Lasker, Zurich 1934](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1007985)

```
[fen "r4rk1/pp3ppp/1qpQ1n2/4nN2/8/1B2P3/PP3PPP/2R2RK1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rae8 2. Ne7+ (2. Rc5 Nfd7) Kh8 3. Qxe5 Ng8
```

It's Black to play. So  if 18...Rae8, then how can White continue to get an advantage? 
If 19.Ne7+ Kh8  20.Qxe5 Ng8, Black seems to get the piece back with a good position. 
Also 19.Rc5 Nfd7 doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I'm I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 20...Ng8 21. Nc6! Re5 22. Ne5 and wins f7 too due to the dual threats of Nd7 and Nf7, both winning the exchange. So, 22...Nf6 is forced, and white is just winning there.

It is going to be Q vs. R, B, and two pawns; but the problem is that white will control both files, and the black K is still not safe.

```
[fen "r4rk1/pp3ppp/1qpQ1n2/4nN2/8/1B2P3/PP3PPP/2R2RK1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rae8 2. Ne7+ (2. Rc5 Nfd7) Kh8 3. Qxe5 Ng8 4. Nxc6! Rxe5 5. Nxe5 Nf6 {forced} 6. Nf7 Kg8 7. Rfd1 {is crushing since you cannot take on f7 due to mate with Rc8}
```